# how to include listings using \lstinputlisting

Tags: listings

In a document embedding java code (actually processing) I can successfully embed listings using:

```
\begin[language=java]{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

In an attempt to increase convenience, I wrote a new command that abbreviates this to:

```
\java

\end{lstlisting}
```

This works fine.  However, in many instances it would be better to keep the listing external. This should be:

```
lstinputlisting[language=java]{code/openglprocessing/s00trianglegouraud.pde}
```

which I abbreviate:

```
\newcommand{\incjava}{\lstinputlisting[language=Java]}

\incjava{code/openglprocessing/s00trianglegouraud.pde}
```

Both formulations result in the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.160 \incjava
              {code/openglprocessing/s00trianglegouraud.pde}
```

While on the subject, is there any way to define a standard directory to avoid having to repeatedly refer to code/openglprocessing, in a similar manner to the graphics path for \includegraphics?

```
\graphicspath{ {img/} }
```

Comment: Advice: Define a macro for the editor instead of LaTeX, the source code will be much more readable that way.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `\java`, I would define an environment `java`. Then the `\begin` and `\end` macros are properly matched in the source code, also making some TeX editors happy. Such an environment is defined by `\lstnewenvironment` of package `listings`. Also an optional argument is added. Then the user can set some options in `\begin{java}[...]` for a particular listings.

The `\incjava` command should work as is does in the following example. Also this macro is given an optional argument for options to the particular listings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{java}[1][]{%
  \lstset{language=Java,#1}%
}{}

\newcommand*{\incjava}[1][]{%
  \lstinputlisting[{language=Java,#1}]%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{java}
public class Example implements StringHandler {

    /**
     * Prints the given string.
     *
     * @param s  the given string
     */
    @Override
    public void handle(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
\end{java}

\incjava{Example.java}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

There is no `\listingspath` for listing files, but `\input@path` for TeX files can be defined, e.g.:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\input@path}{}
\g@addto@macro\input@path{{code/openglprocessing/}}
\makeatother
```

Each entry should be surrounded by curly braces and end with the directory separator.

Another variant is setting the environment variable `TEXINPUTS` to include the directory, example for TeX Live/Linux:

```
TEXINPUTS=:code/openglprocessing
```

The colon (Unix) or semicolon (Windows) at the beginning is important, because then the previous search path (from `texmf.cnf`) is added at this place.