# Step-by-step in report

Tags: listings

I am trying to explain a program code step-by-step, but I would like to show what we have atm in each example, without retyping.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
#!/bin/sh
export A=2
\end{lstlisting}

We have
\begin{example}
\( A =2 \)
\end{example}

\begin{lstlisting}
export B=2
\end{lstlisting}

And we have now
\begin{example}
\( A = 2 \)
\( B = 2 \)
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Is there an environment, which stores these?
Or is there a better style in doing this, while still showing all variables already declared?

Comment: How about you check [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197509/167081). You can escape some text in `listings` environment.

Comment: This is technically very nice, but doesn't solve my problem, as the real code uses `lstinputlistings` and is written by somebody else

Comment: Alright, how about [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249065/167081)?

Comment: Not really, I should pobably remove the listings tag, as the problem is more with the `example`-pseudoenvironment